# why this error coming when compiling how to solve implicit declaration of function?

Tags: c, gcc-warning

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    float val [4][2],a[4];
    int j,i,y;
    
    float cordianation_entry() {  
        printf("enter your cordianation-");
        scanf("%f,%f",&val[0][0],&val[0][1]);
        for(j=1;j<4;j++) {
            printf("enter station %d coordination-",j);
            scanf("%f,%f",&val[j][0],&val[j][1]);
       }    
    }
    
    float results_analysis() {
      
       for(i=1;i<4;i++) { 
        a[i] = (pow((val[i][0]-val[0][0]),2)) + (pow((val[i][1]-val[0][1]),2));
        a[i]=sqrt(a[i]);
        printf("\n*distance to station %d is %f\n",i,a[i]);
        if(a[i]<100)
        printf("\tDistance is Low");
        else if(a[i]<1000 && a[i]>=100)
        printf("\tDistance is Moderate");
        else 
        printf("\tDistance is High");
       }
```

compiler dose not read this minimum function
float minimum() {

```
        if(a[1]<a[2]&&a[1]<a[3])
        printf("station 1 is the nearest");
        else if(a[2]<a[3]&&a[2]<a[1])
        printf("station 2 is the nearest");
        else if(a[3]<a[1]&&a[3]<a[2])
        printf("station 2 is the nearest");
    }
    
    
    
    
    }
```

compiler dose not detect minimum function how to solve it
when it compile it shows an error message impilicit decleration of function minimum

```
void main() {   
   cordianation_entry();
   results_analysis();
   minimum();
}
```

Comment: please help me i cannot find solution

Comment: what is the error here

Comment: Is this the order of the functions as in the full code? If not can you post the entire code so i can see if the order of declaration is corrrect?

Comment: how to correct it this is the full code but minimum function dosent recognize by the compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you did not use `{}` parenthesis correctly. In particular this function:

```
float results_analysis() {
  
   for(i=1;i<4;i++) { 
    a[i] = (pow((val[i][0]-val[0][0]),2)) + (pow((val[i][1]-val[0][1]),2));
    a[i]=sqrt(a[i]);
    printf("\n*distance to station %d is %f\n",i,a[i]);
    if(a[i]<100)
    printf("\tDistance is Low");
    else if(a[i]<1000 && a[i]>=100)
    printf("\tDistance is Moderate");
    else 
    printf("\tDistance is High");
   }
}   // <--- Missing in your code
```

and there is a `}` parenthesis that is not supposed to be there:

```
float minimum() {

    if(a[1]<a[2]&&a[1]<a[3])
    printf("station 1 is the nearest");
    else if(a[2]<a[3]&&a[2]<a[1])
    printf("station 2 is the nearest");
    else if(a[3]<a[1]&&a[3]<a[2])
    printf("station 2 is the nearest");
}

// }  <--- Wrong
```